# FluentValidation to use enum with WithMessage?

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have a class:

```
public class CustomerType
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

And an enum for validation errors:

```
public enum CustomerTypeError
{
    None,
    NotNumber,
}
```

And then I have the validator class which currently looks like this:

```
public class CustomerTypeValidator : AbstractValidator<CustomerType>
{
    public CustomerTypeValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Number).GreaterThanOrEqualTo("").WithMessage("Number must be greater than 0.");
    }
}
```

I don't want to hard-code the message, and I'm not using resource files as this is the server-side of the application. I would like to return a CustomerTypeError value.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using .WithState() and then reading CUstomState from the ValidationFailure object. This does the trick.